# Swift Perfect oAuth2.0 in aws

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, perfect

I want to use Swift Perfect framework for serv. I found that AWS supports Swift executable. I'm trying to use IAM service in Swift. But, not finding any tutorial to implement it properly. Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: Official tutorial is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/

But your question should not be on stackoverflow

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Oh! Sorry for that. Thanks for the link